# Creating canonical basis vectors in R?

Tags: r, vector

Is there an efficient way of creating the canonical basis vectors:

```
e_1=c(1,0,0,...), 

e_2=c(0,1,0,...),

e_3=c(0,0,1,...),

...
```

for arbitrary lengths in R and probably large p?

I know that I could do

```
e_1 = rep(0,p) 
e_1[1] = 1
```

and so on or `diag(p)[1]` ... But I wonder if there is a more efficient way since I only need one at a time in a loop.

Comment: Not sure how efficient it is, but there's `replace(numeric(10), 4, 1)` for e_4 in a 10-d space. Of course, you can wrap whatever you come up with in a function so you don't need to retype it. `make_basis <- function(p, n) replace(numeric(p), n, 1)` or similar.

Comment: @Frank Sounds good enough to me. If you post it as an answer,  I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be somewhat shorter with `replace`:

```
make_basis <- function(k, p = 10) replace(numeric(p), k, 1)

# usage
e_4 = make_basis(4)
e_4
# [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Or perhaps `tabulate(4, nbins = 10)`